# Google Sign-in and Google Sheets API V4

Tags: google-api, google-sheets-api, google-api-nodejs-client

I am trying without success to ["Add Google Sign-In to Your Web App"](https://developers.google.com/identity/sign-in/web/) and then use Node.js with [Google Sheets API V4](https://developers.google.com/sheets/api/quickstart/nodejs) to be able allow my app to use the sheets api on behalf of the user (with scope: https://www.googleapis.com/auth/spreadsheets).

I'm really confused on how to achieve this. Reading through most of the documentation from [OAuth2](https://developers.google.com/identity/protocols/OAuth2) doesn't clarify me best practices to achieve this with the Google Sign-In button.

Furthermore, I haven't found any documentation/guides related to this. I was hoping someone can guide me towards the right direction.

P.S: I managed to use the sheets api by following the [Node.js quickstart for Sheets API](https://developers.google.com/sheets/api/quickstart/nodejs), which allows me to achieve authorization through console, however I believe using the Sign-In button might simplify the process while making a nicer UX.

Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

[Google Sign-In](https://developers.google.com/identity/sign-in/web/) is like what it says, for signing-in. However, it's not enough to authorize you to use Sheets API methods because if you read the [Authorize Requests](https://developers.google.com/sheets/api/guides/authorizing) docs, it clearly states that you need to use OAuth2 plus there are scopes to consider (read-only, read/write, etc).

You are correct to follow the guidelines where you used OAuth2.0. Just create your own custom button. Grab a Google button image in the web and use that.

Comment: I think I'll do as you suggest. I was hoping, when I read you can retrieve access tokens callling [GoogleUser.getAuthResponse(includeAuthorizationData)](https://developers.google.com/identity/sign-in/web/reference#gapiauth2authresponse), that they were talking about the same access tokens required to authorize the app's requests and there was a chance of sending this data to the [Node.js quickstart for Sheets API](https://developers.google.com/sheets/api/quickstart/nodejs). I'm guessing they are different kinds of Auth2 after all?

Comment: @sashaskull what did you eventually choose to do ? Google Sign in with Sheets authorization or just sheets ?